# do a task when receive local notification push

Tags: ios, push-notification, local

I want to do some things when local push notification fired in ios app. Only app is active, some tasks will be called. I tried something in didReceiveLocalNotification but it doesn't work.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveLocalNotification");
    [self doSomethings];
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create the notification?

Comment: What are "some tasks" and which other tasks are not processed?